# Change VPS root password

Tags: password, vps

Is it advised to change root password of a VPS ? If yes, kindly give me the commands to do the same.

Comment: How do you suppose this is done differently from a normal machine? What is your distribution?

Comment: @guntbert , the VPS in question has 14.04 running on it.

Answer (score 2):

This is very vague... What are the circumstances? Does someone know your password?

Generally if you believe password to be:

- Weak Password (Not very strong)
- Known by someone else. (who is not trusted) (Compromised)

You can change the password by logging to your account and typing: `passwd` or `passwd username`(if you would like to change another user's password.)

However if you do believe your system (or password) to be compromised you should check your system for any unauthorized access, data breaches and or backdoors which may allow an attacker access to your server even after changing your passwords.

I would also recommend changing all other system passwords, such as MySql account passwords.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just got a new VPS. Wondering if I should change the default root password. Is it a normal security practice ?

Comment: Yes, I would personally recommend it. Normally such passwords are stored insecurely within the billing system and sometimes sent via email.

Comment: Thank you. Kindly let me know how to add a new user to 14.04 with admin privileges.

Comment: Open a new question, and I will answer it :-) - It's hard to format a proper response within a comment box in addition it will help others.